# What is this purple substance that grew under my carpet?

Tags: mold, carpet, vinyl

[image: view of affected area]

[image: close up of purple substance]

I moved into my house this past spring. One floor with linoleum/vinyl-looking floor had a reddish stain. No big deal! I covered it with a carpet. Today noticed that the formerly light red stain is now solid deep purple. I’m guessing mold- any other ideas?

There is no unusual stain or substance on the underside of the carpet.

I sprayed with a healthy amount of white vinegar, waited an hour, and mopped. None of the purple substance came off. I would expect mold to wipe off.

If it’s mold, is it possible this indicates a water problem below the floor? There are no pipes in that floor, and the floor below has no evidence of leaks.

Comment: If its confined to this area, then perhaps spillage of red liquid or colour leaching from the covering.

Comment: Send a sample for testing. Any reply on here  is merely a guess.

Comment: Does this room get a lot of direct sunlight? The region has some sharp edges that appear to correspond to the rug - so that the people area is 100% under the rug? If so, it is probably organic. I have seen something similar in a case that did not have a water problem, the stuff just didn't need more than ambient humidity to survive (east coast).

Comment: Looks like, whatever it is, it comes from the rug as it seems to be more prevalent on the tiles than the grout, suggesting contact is key, and the sharp edges Blarg mentioned. Does the rug appear to have been damaged at all?

Comment: I don't see anything on the parts of the rug I can see.  Was there something like a chair sitting on top of the rug at the top right?

Comment: Does sunlight hit that area in the shape of the discoloration? Or maybe you use a steam mop? Could be the rug traps the heat against the vinyl resulting in a chemical reaction and discoloration

Comment: The bold purple color was 100% under the rug. The room gets indirect sunlight. @blarg

Comment: @monkeyzeuss those non-purple areas don’t correspond with anything that was or is visible. Maybe something inside the floor?

Comment: Does it really matter? The carpet has to go and so does the linoleum. Replaced with anything else, I wouldn't be worried. Replaced with same, you'd better treat the subfloor with something first. I'd presume there's no insulation underneath, that this is a, half-outside- the-envelope addition, and it condenses humidity on the floor.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the room location? Is this ground floor, any basement beneath, any potential water source (e.g. up from slab-on-grade)?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is, it seems to correspond to a walking path. Something gets watered in the upper right and then something gets water on the left side and then the room is exited.

To me, it seems like a reaction between the carpet and flooring. It baffles me that none of it is on the bottom of that rug.

Can you scrub it off at all?

What are those non-purple lines in the upper-right and lower-left?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is mold, and it is being somewhat kept in check by even the indirect sunlight. I have seen similar purple mold on vinyl tiles, in a location also got strong indirect light. The coverage of the area would die back more in the summer and return in the winter as the scattered light got stronger and weaker.

Unfortunately, the mold is likely not on the surface which is why surface cleaner does nothing. I would suggest using a UV light on the area (or a small section) to see if that works. You'll have to do a bit or research to know how much and how long to expose (depends on light brightness and distance).

If this does work, there is still a real risk that it will return even if you kill everything visible - there is a good chance the true home of the mold is underside of the tile, and you're only seeing it's frontier explorers. If so, replacement of the tile is the only solution (plus mold remediation of the substrate, which may include identifying a source of water ingress = $$).

In the case I know of, they eventually replaced the vinyl tile with hardwood. I don't believe there was any major issues with the subfloor it was just near an exterior door and the tiny bit of extra ambient moisture was enough. So remediation may not be a big deal.